# Filter row based on max & unique value in one column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

[image: Expected output]Its a bit tricky to explain, Ill try my best, query below. I have a df as below. I need to filter rows by group based on maximum pop in country column but which has not already occurred in the above groups. (As per output (image), the  reason why A didnt feature in group2 because it had already occured in Group 1)

In short, I need to get unique values in country column at the same time get maximum value in pop (on a group level). I hope picture can convey what I could not. (Tidyverse solution preferred)

[![Expected output][2]][2]

```
df<- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), country = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "E", "F", "A", "E", "G"), pop = c(200L, 100L, 50L, 200L, 150L, 120L, 200L, 150L, 
100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: What if G also appeared in Group A with a value of 150, then would the final result be the same?  So if a country "looses" in one group, can it "win" another group with a lower value?

Comment: I think OP wants to eliminate country from next iterations only.  Its pop values doesn't matter!  Let Vaibhav clarify

Answer (score 4):

I think this will do.  Explanation of syntax

- split the data into list for each group
- leave first group (as it will be used as `.init` in next step but after filtering for the max of `pop` value.
- use `purrr::reduce` here which will reduce the list of tibbles to a single tibble
- iterations used in `reduce`

  - `.init` used as filtered first group
  - thereafter countries in previous groups removed through `anti_join`
  - this data filtered for max `pop` again
  - added the previously filtered countries by `bind_rows()`
- Thus, in the end we will have desired tibble.

```
df %>% group_split(Group) %>% .[-1] %>%
  reduce(.init =df %>% group_split(Group) %>% .[[1]] %>% 
               filter(pop == max(pop)), 
             ~ .y  %>%
               anti_join(.x, by = c("country" = "country")) %>% 
               filter(pop == max(pop)) %>%
               bind_rows(.x) %>% arrange(Group)) 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Group country   pop
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1     1 A         200
2     2 E         150
3     3 G         100
```

Comment: Edited (Corrected it)

Comment: This also works in the case where a country has a higher value in a group where it is not the highest.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a helper function that writes the maximum pop from each group in a vector and use it to filter the dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
max_values <- c()

helper <- function(dat, ...){
  dat <- dat[!(dat %in% max_values)] # exclude maximum values from previous groups
  max_value <- max(dat) # get current max. value
  max_values <<- c(max_values, max_value) # append 
  return(max_value)
}

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(pop == helper(pop))
```

which gives you:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group country   pop
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1     1 A         200
2     2 E         150
3     3 H         120
```

Data used:

```
> df
   Group country pop
1      1       A 200
2      1       B 100
3      1       C  50
4      2       A 200
5      2       E 150
6      2       F 120
7      3       A 200
8      3       E 150
9      3       G 100
10     3       H 120
```

Comment: This works even when a country has a higher value in a group where it is not the highest.

Comment: This needs the use a global variable (<<- writing to parent environment). Generally, it would be prefered not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility, but
**Overly Simplified** in that it does not take into account
the possibility of a group having a higher population in a Group where
it does not win.

```
library(dplyr)
df<- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), country = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "E", "F", "A", "E", "G"), pop = c(200L, 100L, 50L, 200L, 150L, 120L, 200L, 150L, 
100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

df %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  summarize(popmax = max(pop))  %>% 
  inner_join(df, by = c("popmax" = 'pop')) %>% 
  rename(country = country.y) %>% 
  select(-country.x) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  arrange(Group) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  arrange(country) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%  
  select(Group, country, popmax) %>% 
  rename(pop = popmax)
```

My answer fails (while other answers don't)  with this data set:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~Group, ~ country, ~pop,
  1     ,         'A',    200,
  1     ,         'B',    100,
  1     ,         'C',     50,
  1     ,         'G',    150,
  2     ,         'A',    200,
  2     ,         'E',    150,
  2     ,         'F',    120,
  3     ,         'A',    200,
  3     ,         'E',    150,
  3     ,         'G',    100
)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
@Crestor who is claiming that my answer is not correct.

- My answer is correct because my code gives the desired output as requested by OP.
- Your objection that my code does not work on another scenario may be correct, but in this setting it is irrelevant, as my answer was only intended to solve the task at hand.
- Here is the answer to your raised scenario with this dataset:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    country = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "E", "F", "A", "E", "G"), 
    pop = c(200L, 100L, 250L, 220L, 150L, 120L, 200L, 150L, 100L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

expected output by Crestor:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Group country   pop
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1     1 C         250
2     2 A         220
3     3 E         150
```

My code for your scenario @crestor

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
group_by(country) %>% 
arrange(Group) %>% 
filter(pop == max(pop)) %>% 
group_by(Group) %>% 
filter(pop == max(pop))
```

Output:

```
  Group country   pop
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1     1 C         250
2     2 A         220
3     3 E         150
```

**Original answer to the question by OP**

**To keep it simple:** First `arrange` to bring your dataset in position. Then `group_by` and keep first row in each group with  `slice`. Then `group_by` `Group` and `filter` the max `pop`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  arrange(country, pop) %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  filter(pop==max(pop))
```

Output:

```
  Group country   pop
  <int> <chr>   <int>
1     1 A         200
2     2 E         150
3     3 G         100
```

Comment: One question would be: why, in your code, was A put in Group 1?  That appears to be unrelated to the fact that it is in group 1 previous to being in group 2.  But what if the Group order is what breaks the tie, not country order?

Comment: Thank you for your valuable comment. `A` is part of `Group1`. Anyway it does not matter in this case where subsequent `A`s are put. Countries after the first max occurence are irrelevant as the assumption is: "maximum pop in country column but which has not already occurred in the above groups". The logic requires thinking outside the box and unless another proof is presented this approach seems to work.

Comment: This is not correct. For example, in this case:   df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Group, ~country, ~pop,
  1L,      "A", 200L,
  1L,      "B", 100L,
  1L,      "C", 250L,
  2L,      "A", 220L,
  2L,      "E", 150L,
  2L,      "F", 120L,
  3L,      "A", 200L,
  3L,      "E", 150L,
  3L,      "G", 100L
)

Comment: The answer is specific on the question. For your dataset change: `group_by(country)` with `group_by(country, pop)`. Let me know what you think? Cheers.

Comment: Even changing group_by(country) with group_by(country, pop), it doesn't obtain the correct answer.

Comment: @ Crestor, I have now understood what you are getting at. Nevertheless I insist that the code is not labeled incorrect. Your objection is interesting and may be a new question how to handle ties in groups conditional on other columns. I provide a solution for your specific dataset. Please see my edit!

Comment: I agree with @crestor that the strategy is not correct.  Getting an exactly same answer as expected for a very small sample doesn't imply that logic is also correct.

Comment: check now with this dataset.`df1 <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), 
                      country = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "E", "F", "A", "E", "G", "G", "E", "I"), 
                      pop = c(200L, 100L, 250L, 220L, 150L, 120L, 200L, 150L, 100L, 100L, 150L, 98L
                      )), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                      ))` Actually in the given code only 3 groups are there and you are filtering 2 times.  For n groups, with your strategy you have to filter n-1 times

Comment: @ AnilGoyal. I really appreciate your time. In order to keep the overview we should agree that: 1. my 1st code brings OP's desired result in this special case. 2. Crestor is right that it doesn't work in another dataset. 3. Therefore I provide my 2nd code for the data set of Crestor, where this code also brings the desired result. 4. Now a third data set occurs (AnilGoyal). 5. If someone succeeds in showing me that one of the above provided answers (AnilGoyal, SEcker, Harlan Nelson) given, applies correctly to all 3 data sets (1st OP, 2nd Crestor, 3rd AnilGoyal) I take back my assertion.

Comment: Your source code obtains the same result for the example. But it doesn't meet the specifications (written by the OP) "filter rows by group based on maximum pop in country column but which has not already occurred in the above groups".